# GIT log shows ALL previous merges as ahead when it's not

Tags: git, version-control, merge

So, I have the `master` branch and a `uat` branch. All codes changes are on `master` and then, when ready to roll out to the server, are periodically merged from `master` into the `uat`.

I'm using GitX, and notice that my `uat` branch is starting to show a branch line for *each* merge to `uat`; instead of the expected two branch lines of `master` and `uat`.

[image: Weird Branch Lines]

If I push my changes to `origin/master` the lines above change to show the expected 2 lines.  If `uat` is then pushed, it goes back to what you see.

At first I thought this was a GitX quirk, but my GIT states that my `uat` is **11 commits ahead** when `master` was *just* merged into `uat`.  If I count the number of extra branch lines, it matches the 11 merges.

So I'm starting to think that I had a random detached head or something somewhere that's made things so astray, as one of these merges has `master` instead of `refs/heads/master` and another a detached head.

Was wondering if anyone knows what this is, and if anything should be done to clean it up before it gets out of control.

Appreciate any help

Comment: What's your branch structure by using `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`?

Comment: Shows up just like the posted image above (just in ASCII)

Comment: The graph should be different. Can you add the output in your question?

Comment: the graph matches the same as what I see in the GitX program with that command.  Unfortunately the comment box is limited in characters and the command output is large, but it is exactly the same as what GitX is showing.

Comment: You can use `git branch -vv` to check branch `uat` is tracking `origin/uat` or `origin/master`. if `uat` is tracking `origin/master`, you can set `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/uat uat`.

Comment: thanks Marina, about the tip as the UAT wasn't tracking, so have made it tracking.  Seemed to look okay for a bit, but merge another load of `master` into `uat` and the graph has again grown.   It seems right if I trace the lines, but I just can't figure out why it shows ALL `uat` merges ahead of all my more recent commits.  Is this just a GIT/GitX thing, as I don't remember other projects showing the same thing.   It's not a show stopper, just going to get to a point where I'm going to have to scroll both vertically and horizontally for two branches.  hmmm.

Comment: After using `origin/uat` to track `uat` branch, the git status should be right. If you merge `master` into `uat` without pushing to remote, `git status` will say 1 commit ahead of `origin/uat`. After pushing `uat` to remote, and `git status` will say your local `uat` is up-to-date with `origin/uat`.

Comment: still seems to be showing more branches.  Have done two merges from `master` to `uat` since and now my `uat` has gone from 11 commits to 13 commits ahead.   A bit concerning since by the time this project is finished I'm going to have a few hundred branch lines showing all over the place for 2 branches.  I'm running  git v2.11.0-81, if that helps?

Comment: What's the output of `git branch -vv` now?

Comment: master                 fca76e6 [origin/master: ahead 8] _(commit comment)_

Comment: uat                    a957628 [origin/uat] Merge branch 'refs/heads/master' into uat

Comment: hmm...seems to have cleared things up based on that command you passed thru before.   Actually, now I've done a few more commits and merges into UAT, seems to be behaving.  :)  Thanks Marina.                  Can you please add that comment about tracking as a solution and I'll accept it for you. :)

Comment: Glad to hear your problem been solved. And I posted in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the tracking branch for `uat` by `git branch -vv`.
If uat is not tracked by `origin/uat`, you can set `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/uat uat`.

Then when you use `git status`, it will show the right status between local `uat` branch and `origin/uat`.

Such as if you merge `master` into `uat` without pushing to remote, `git status` will say `1 commit ahead of origin/uat`. After pushing `uat` to remote, and `git status` will say your `local uat is up-to-date with origin/uat`.